# Handle un-formatted/missing html tag inside div tag using html and python only

Tags: python, html, jinja2

I am trying to fetch emails in `python` and show those emails inside `div container`. Now if `email` contains all correct open and closed tags then it shows up correctly but if email has missing `html tags` then my whole layout goes dizzling around.

How can I force email html to be shown inside div tag.

Note: I am using jinja2 to directly show html inside div tag by:

```
<div class="card-body">
{{e['body']|safe}}
</div>
```

Comment: have you looked into trying [tidy](https://pythonhosted.org/pytidylib/)?

Answer (score 0):

Basically that is what `safe` filter does. You expect to have proper html code at `e['body']`. Consider performing some validation of email body to make sure that it's correct HTML code or prepare some function that will convert your email to proper HTML code.

Comment: Yes thats what I am looking for, if someone can help me find same